# jQuery timepicker and validate not working

Tags: jquery, validation, datepicker, timepicker

I have two jQuery scripts that are not working on my page, a validate script, and a timepicker. They are not working at all, however datepicker is working.  I get the following error for the time picker:

Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'timepicker'

However that is the only error I am getting.

This is the code I am using:

```
    <script src="/js/jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js"></script>
    <script src='/sorttable.js'></script>
    <script src="/js/jquery.ui.timepicker.js"></script>
    <script src="/jquery.validate.js"></script>


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/css/appmanager.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/overcast/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/js/jquery.ui.timepicker.css" />

        <script >
            jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery(".content").hide();
            //toggle the componenet with class msg_body
            jQuery(".heading").click(function()
            {
                jQuery(this).next(".content").slideToggle(500);
            });
            });
        </script>
        <script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function($){
                    $("#datepicker").datepicker();

            });
        </script>

        <script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            $( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker();
            });
            </script>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('#timepicker').timepicker( {
                        showAnim: 'blind'
                    } );
                });
            </script>
    <script>


    $().ready(function() {

        $("#newapp").validate({
            rules: {
                facility: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 3
                },
                disclaimer: {
                    required: true,
                },
                department: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 3
                },
                address: {
                    required: true
                },
                requestor: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 2
                },
                callback: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 7
                },
                language: "required"
            },
            messages: {
                facility: {
                    required: "Please enter a facility",
                    minlength: "Facility name must be at least 3 characters"
                },
                department: {
                    required: "Please enter a department",
                    minlength: "Department name must be at least 3 characters"
                },
                address: {
                    required: "Please enter a address",
                    minlength: "Address must be at least 5 characters"
                },
                requestor: {
                    required: "Please enter a requestor",
                    minlength: "Requestor name must be at least 3 characters"
                },
                callback: {
                    required: "Please enter a callback number",
                    minlength: "Callback number must be at least 7 characters"
                },
                language: {
                    required: "Please enter a language"
                }
            }
        });

    });

    </script>
```

And the HTML:

```
    <p>Date: <input type="text" style="width:100px;" id="datepicker" name="date" value=""/>
    Time :<input id="timepicker" class="hasTimepicker" type="text" value="" name="time" style="width: 70px;"></input></p>
    <p>Client (Other): <input type="text" style="width:173px;" id="client" name="clientother" value=""/></p>
    <p>Facility: <input type="text" style="width:215px;" id="facility" name="facility" value=""/></p>
    <p>Department: <input type="text" style="width:186px;" id="department" name="department" value=""/></p>
    <p>Address: <input type="text" style="width:210px;" id="address" name="address" value=""/></p>
    <p>Requestor: <input type="text" style="width:197px;" id="requestor" name="requestor" value=""/></p>
    <p>Provider: <input type="text" style="width:210px;" id="provider" name="provider" value=""/></p>
    <p>Callback #: <input type="text" style="width:198px;" id="callback" name="callback" value=""/></p>
    </div>
    <div style="Float:right; width:50%">
    <p>Language: <input type="text" style="width:210px;" id="language" name="language" value=""/></p>
    <p>Medicaid: <select name="medicaid" style="width:225px;" id="medicaid">
    <option value="1">No Medicaid</option>
    <option value="2">Primary Medicaid</option>
    <option value="3">Seccondary Medicaid</option></select></p>
    <p>Medicaid ID: <input type="text" style="width:194px;" id="medicaidid" name="medicaidid" value=""/></p>
    <p>LES Name: <input type="text" style="width:209px;" id="name" name="name" value=""/></p>
    <p>LES Date of Birth: <input type="text" style="width:167px;" id="dob" name="dob"  value=""/>        </p>
    <p>Notes: <textarea rows="6" name= "notes" cols="80" id="notes" style="width:242px"></textarea></p>
    <input type="hidden" id="createdby" name="createdby" value"<?php echo $_SESSION['jigowatt']['username']; ?>" />
```

Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: Why do include two different versions of jQuery and jQuery UI? That may be the problem.

Comment: @amb110395 good catch, that was justsome bad leftover code.  I tried removing one and no change.  I get the same behavior with 1.9 or 1.10.  I updated the code above also to show only using one version.

Comment: Also are you sure your CSS links are right? The last one is: href="/js/jquery.ui.timepicker.css". Are you sure you are storing the CSS file in the JS folder?